# Returning an Array confusion... who can explain to me the following not working code?

Tags: java

/* the followng main method calls a sortBySelection() method wich shall return an array, but when printing the array directly from the calling statement i am getting wrong stuff!
the array is being returned and printed correctly using a for loop
if i am to use the Arrays class to print the returned array, java is not accepting my code... what is wrong with the code?
*/

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class xyz {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int [] list = {1,7,4,5,12,205,11,0,1,52,32,3, 27, 72,10, 19, 16};
        //The following line is not printing the returned array!!
        System.out.print("\nthe sorted array is: " + 
        (sortBySelection(list)+"\n"));
        //The following statement is not even accepted by java!!!
        System.out.print("\nthe sorted array is: " + 
        Arrays.toString((sortBySelection(list))+"\n"));
        //The following for loop prints the returned array correctly!!!
        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i]+" ");

        for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
        System.out.print(list[i]+" ");
    }   
    public static int[] sortBySelection(int[] array){
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j=array.length-1; j>=0; j--){
        for (int i=0 ; i<j; i++){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                //swap
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] =array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
        return array;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'd guess you need to change `Arrays.toString((sortBySelection(list))+"\n"))` to `Arrays.toString(sortBySelection(list)) + "\n";`, and use that whenever you print out a list.

Comment: `what is wrong with the code?` Well, what is wrong with it? It's your job to tell us and we can then help you fixing it.

Comment: `Arrays.toString((sortBySelection(list))+"\n"));` should be `Arrays.toString(sortBySelection(list))+"\n");` note correct parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print("\nthe sorted array is: " + 
Arrays.toString((sortBySelection(list))+"\n"));
```

The problem with this is you are calling Arrays.toString on a String. You can fix by fixing the parentheses

```
System.out.print("\nthe sorted array is: " + 
  Arrays.toString(sortBySelection(list))+"\n");
```

Comment: thanks, the parenthesis fixed the statement that java did not accept ... but how about the result from the call of method "sortBySelection(list), why i am i getting this output: the sorted array is: [I@2a139a55